# I committed and pushed a useless big bitmap - should I repair the repo?

Tags: git

I accidentally committed and pushed a big bitmap (35MB) which I forgot to delete from my project's directory and which turns out to be totally useless. Is that something I should worry about?

Since that time I haven't pushed nor committed anything. Also nobody pulled it. What are my options to fix this commit? Is it necessary/recommended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that nobody has pulled from the repository, that suggests that you're in good communication with everyone who might be pulling from the repository.  In that case, I would be inclined to rewrite history to remove that file - it's annoying to bloat everyone's repositories by 35MB for no good reason.  You can do that by telling your colleagues not to touch the repository, resetting to the last-but-one commit as soon as possible, and then force-pushing your reset branch.  You've said that your most recent commit was the one that included the bitmap, so (assuming you're in the `master` branch, and pushing to `master` in `origin`) you can do the following:

```
# Move your current branch back so that it points to the previous commit,
# but leave your working tree as it was (but with everything unstaged):
git reset HEAD^

# Force push your master branch to the remote repository:
git push -f origin master
```

Then you can carry on as before, this time being careful not to stage the large bitmap :)